# Print Map array in JSON format

Tags: go

I am working on a Go project that uses the serpwow api to search google for a given term.

Once I have the list of websites, I am trying to print the values which are being stored in a map in Json format. There is only one column in the map which contains the title as this is the only information I am interested in.

Here is a snippet of the code I currently have to print the results:

```
// retrieve the search results as JSON
response, error := serpwow.GetJSON(parameters, apiKey)

// print the response, or error, if one occurred
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(error)
} else {
    //extract each title from organic results
    fmt.Println(responseJson)
    for _, item := range response["organic_results"].([]interface{}) {
        title := item.(map[string]interface{})["title"]
        titleJson, _ := json.Marshal(title)
        fmt.Printf(titleJson)
        //fmt.Printf("%v", item.(map[string]interface{})["title"])
    }
```

the output is:

"The 10 Best Pizza Places in Dublin - TripAdvisor""Domino's Pizza: Pizza for Delivery or Takeaway Near You""10 Of The Best Pizza Places In Dublin | www.98fm.com""Pizza Bucket List: The Nine Best Spots To Get Your Fix In ...""10 Best Pizzas in Dublin - A slice of the city for every price point""Looking for the best slice of pizza in Dublin? Here's where to ...""Apache Pizza. Pizza Delivery \u0026 Takeaway Stores throughout ...""Four Star Pizza Ireland, Pizza Delivery at its finest!""Pizza Takeaways and Restaurants in Dublin | Order from Just ...""Pizza Delivery, Deals \u0026 Takeaway | Order Online with Pizza ..."

As you can see the output is not formatted in JSON. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `fmt` package knows nothing about JSON. If you want JSON output, encode your input into JSON. Use the `encoding/json` package.

Comment: Your output is formatted as JSON. You're taking a single `string` value, marshaling it to JSON, and printing it. The JSON representation of the string `foo` is `"foo"`, which is the output you're seeing. Everything is working correctly. If you want the output in some other way, you'll have to explain how you want your output structured.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to encode string (title), however you have to build an object first, and then encode it and print:

```
// Or any other struct/type which follows the format of JSON you want
var titles []string
for _, item := range response["organic_results"].([]interface{}) {
    title := item.(map[string]interface{})["title"]
    titles = append(titles, title)     
}

res, err := json.Marshal(titles)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```